# CI-4 how to show multiple tables in one page

Tags: codeigniter-4

good day all,

since i'm new in Code Igniter 4 (i was a native PHP self-learner) and i'm new in MVC, my question is how can i show multiple tables in one page ?

i have a dashboard view with 2 tables inside. one is for display students data and the other is for teachers data. there is no relation between tables, so i can't join the tables.

i have successfully show one of the table (student or teacher) but i can't show both tables in dashboard at once. i think i have to pass 2 models into controller function but i just can't figure it out how to do it.

any help will be appreciated

here is parts of my codes (successfully showing data from 1 table) :

Controller

```
use App\Models\mStudent;
    class Admin extends BaseController
    {
      public function index()
      {
          $model = new mStudent();
          $data['title'] = 'Students';
          $data['getStudents'] = $model->getStudents();

          echo view('admin/header', $data);
          echo view('admin/top_menu');
          echo view('admin/side_menu');
          echo view('admin/dashboard', $data);
          echo view('admin/footer');
      }
```

Model

```
public function getStudents()
          {
            return $this->findAll();
          }
    
     public function getTeachers()
          {
            return $this->findAll();
          }
```

View

```
<!-- students table-->
    
            <table class="table table-bordered text-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 10px; text-align: center;">No</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">NAME</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">Class</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php $no = 1;
                foreach ($getStudents as $students) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?= $no; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $students['name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $students['class'] ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php $no++;
                } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>

        
    <!-- teacher table-->
    
            <table class="table table-bordered text-sm" id="defaulttable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 10px; text-align: center;">No</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">NAME</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center;">ID</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php $no = 1;
                foreach ($getTeachers as $teachers) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?= $no; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $teachers['name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $teachers['id'] ?></td>
                  </tr>
                <?php $no++;
                } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Dynamic Data to the View](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

In your Controller, *right below* `$data['getStudents'] = $model->getStudents();` add:

```php
$data['getTeachers'] = $model->getTeachers();
```

##### Addendum

Then in your model, return the respective result sets. I.e:

*Model*

```php
public function getStudents()
{
    return $this->db->table("students")->get()->getResultArray();
}

public function getTeachers()
{
    return $this->db->table("teachers")->get()->getResultArray();
}
```

Comment: since teacher data is in another table, how can i tell CI4 that get student data from students table, get teacher data from teachers table and then load both of the data into 1 view ? i have 2 separate HTML tables to show students and teachers data separately

Comment: @PairunSaklitunov  Please refer to the *Addendum* section.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i looking for

Controller

```
use App\Models\mStudent;
use App\Models\mTeacher;
    class Admin extends BaseController
    {
      public function index()
      {
          $model_student = new mStudent();
          $model_teacher = new mTeacher();
          $data = array(
                        'student' => $model_student->getStudents(),
                        'teacher' => $model_teacher->getTeachers()
                  );

          echo view('admin/header');
          echo view('admin/top_menu');
          echo view('admin/side_menu');
          echo view('admin/dashboard', $data);
          echo view('admin/footer');
      }
```

View

```
Students :
<select name="stdid">
  <?php foreach ($student as $std) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $std['stdid']; ?>"><?= $std['stdname']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

Teachers :
<select name="tcrid">
  <?php foreach ($teacher as $tcr) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $tcr['tcrid']; ?>"><?= $tcr['tcrname']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

hope this will help someone out there